# How to write a java program using methods to calculate value of equation?

Tags: java, math, quadratic

I need help writing this in elipse...

Write a java program using methods to calculate value of the below equation

x2+2x+6

Details: 1. create a method called equation(int x), with one argument.
    2. we need to pass an integer as an argument to that function.
    3. The equation() method should calculate the value of the equation after substituting x with the   given value.
    4. an example is shown below:

ex: equation(10)  should give output 126

Comment: your teacher asced for elipse? or eclipse? ah, whatsoever. Questions asking us to solve their homework are off topic.

Comment: @Rose Thanks for joining StackOverflow! In general, questions that don't demonstrate any initial attempt at solving the problem are not well-received. I would recommend (for the next time around) that you include your attempted solution, and explain what challenges you're facing or issues that you're running into. It'll also make for a more meaningful learning experience for you. `:)`

Comment: It would be better for you to attempt question first, if you have any difficulties we are glad to help you.  It will just help you.

Answer (score 3):

```
double equation(int a){
 return Math.pow(a, 2) + 2*a + 6;
}
```

Comment: Should be "return a*a+2*a+6" instead, the current code does not compile as pow returns a double.

Comment: Corrected the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

```
double equation(int a){
 return double(a*a + 2*a + 6);
}
```